# SwiftUI: How to interstellare array of enums?

Tags: swift, image, video, enums, iteration

I have an array of enums where each enum either contains an image or video. I would like to loop through the array and get the values inside each enum. If the enum contains an image I would like get that value and if it contains a video then get that value.

> So how do I loop through an array if enums?

**This is my code:**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

enum ContentSource {
    case image(UIImage)
    case video(AVPlayer)
}

var post : [ContentSource] = []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have a `switch` to figure out what type it is in the loop.

```
import AVKit

var posts : [ContentSource] = []

ForEach(posts){ post in
    switch post {
    case .image(let uIImage):
        Image(uiImage: uIImage)
    case .video(let aVPlayer):
        VideoPlayer(player: aVPlayer)
    }
}
```

Comment: When using this i get this error: `Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder'. Any ideas?

Comment: @Nick then you have to use `ForEach` instead. Very similar implementation. See above.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
enum ContentSource: Hashable {
    case image(UIImage)
    case video(AVPlayer)
}

struct ContentView: View {
@State var posts : [ContentSource] = []

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        ForEach(posts, id: \.self) { item in
            switch(item) {
            case .image(let img):
                Image(uiImage: img).padding(22)
            case .video(let avPlayer):
                VideoPlayer(player: avPlayer)
            }
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        // for testing
        let img = UIImage(systemName: "globe")!
        let av = AVPlayer()
        // let av = AVPlayer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "testvideo", withExtension: "MOV")!)
        posts = [.image(img), .video(av)]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works in regards to looping through the array. But There is two problems. When using list, it has a weird pre-built UI background. How do i get rid of this? The other problem is in regards to displaying the video. `VideoPlayer(player: )` takes a binding, but let avPlayer isnt of type `Binding<AVPlayer>` how do i fix this?

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. With regards to the background, if you don't like the `List`,
 then don't use it. You could use a `ScrollView` and a `ForEach` for example, it is up to you to display the info as you wish.
 Since you did not ask for a particular background, it is not possible to guess what you did not want.
 With regards to "...displaying the video...", you did not
 ask or mentioned anything about a binding in your question.
 Nevertheless, `VideoPlayer(player: avPlayer)` does not take a binding. I'll update my answer with a `ScrollView` and a `VideoPlayer`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this , you can get the associated values and do as you wish with them

```
enum ContentSource {
    case image(UIImage)
    case video(AVPlayer)
}

var post :[ContentSource] = []

let testContent = ContentSource.video(AVPlayer())

switch testContent {
case .image(let img):
    print("i got img")
case .video(let video):
    print("i got video")
}
```

Comment: This isnt really looping through the `post` array, now is it? Its just checking the testContent. Right?