# SwiftUI: How to display one image at a time?

Tags: image, swiftui, scrollview, tiktoktemplate

I have an array of images which I loop through, and display in a scrollView.
This is want I want to achieve:

1. I would like there to only be one visible image at a time. Like TikTok and instagram.
2. I would like the image to take up as much of the screen as possible, while still keeping the aspectRatio.
3. Center image
4. I don’t mind using `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .leading, .trailing])`

This is the code I have so far. As you can see there is two images visible at a time. And even when there is only one image in the array, it isn’t centered, but clings to the top of the screen.

**Any ideas on how to solve this?**

```
 ScrollView(.vertical) {
            ForEach(allRetrievedMedia, id: \.self) { item in
                switch(item) {
                case .image(let img):

                        Image(uiImage: img)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(alignment: .center)
   
                }
            }
        }
```

[image: Image of screen]

Comment: is this related to your previous question that you did not complete,
 here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74275387/swiftui-how-to-interstellare-array-of-enums

Comment: Yes it’s related to that. I just forgot to accept one of the answers as “correct”.

Answer (score 0):

Embed the image in a container and add `.frame(width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height, alignment: .center)` to that container. Then add `.scaledToFill()` method to the image itself. This should do the trick, here's a snippet to help...

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            ForEach(allRetrievedMedia, id: \.self) { item in switch(item) {
                case .image(let img):
                VStack {
                    Image(uiImage: img)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                }.frame(width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height, alignment: .center)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Haven't tried that myself, but should work like a charm. Hope it helps